# Property error when linking SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I'm running into an issue linking SQL servers. The servers I have are:

Server A - SQL Server 2008 R2

Server B - SQL Server 2014

I can set B as a linked server on A with no problem, but setting up A as a linked server on B gets me the error:

> Cannot write property UseRemoteCollation.This property is not
>   available on SQL Server 7.0. (SqlManagerUI)

Is this just an issue with the two servers being different versions? Is there anything I can do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differing "best practices" for using SQL Server Management Studio when managing SQL Server.

1. Use the *same version* of SQL Server Management Studio as that of the server you are managing.  In this case that means you should use SSMS that comes with SQL Server 2014; one source would be [ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46697).
2. Use the latest-and-greatest version of SQL Server Management Studio.  As of now (2018-07-05), that would be SSMS 17.8.1, which is available free from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).